# How to hide the last column of a bound DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataSource that, based on user input, hiding its columns in DataBindingComplete event.
It works fine except when all the columns need to be hidden, the last one to be hidden is always displayed. 
During the debug, I can see that the column is set to visible = false but it has no effect.

I have a workaround that works fine, triggering a timer in the DataBindingComplete event and calling the HideColumns() method but I searching for a better solution.

```
    private void CoverageDGV_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {            
        var datagridview = sender as DataGridView;

        datagridview.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft;            
        datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

        datagridview.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader;            
        datagridview.RowHeadersVisible = true;            
        datagridview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
        datagridview.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;                                                    
        datagridview.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        HideColumns(datagridview);

        //timer1.Enabled = true; // This works fine
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        HideColumns(ShipCoverageDGV);
    }

    private void HideColumns(DataGridView datagridview)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var column = datagridview.Columns[i];
            var itemType = [USER INPUT];
            if (itemType == Glossary.IndirectCOType)
                column.Visible = IndirectCOCheckBox.Checked;
            else if (itemType == Glossary.NotAllocatedType)
                column.Visible = NotAllocatedCheckBox.Checked;
            else
                column.Visible = DirectCOCheckBox.Checked;                    
        }           
    }
```

My question is: is there a solution how to hide all the columns?

Comment: So, you're basically setting `column.Visible` to false for all columns, am I right? Can you simplify the method (we can't access your enums anyway)? Please, consider creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without a runnable example, we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you simply populate a `DataTable` with arbitrary data, bind it and then hide all columns, does it work? If so, start from there and change one thing at a time towards your current code until it stops working and you have found the issue. If not, provide that basic code to us as a basis for us to test and see if we can work out the problem. Otherwise, each and every person who wants to help has to create their own test code. If you want the help, you can do that for us, can't you?

Comment: Fair enough, I'll do that

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: I found the issue. I have some code coming after the DataBindingComplete that use CurrencyManager.SuspendBinding operation. Once calling this command, the last hidden column is getting display back. Not clear why but this is the problem

Answer (score -3):

`dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`